# How do I force a certain URL after a Rails redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, url, redirect, controller

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have the following in the create method of my controller

```
    format.html { redirect_to controller: "my_objects", action: "index", notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
```

However when I redirect, the URL is actually

```
http://mydomein.devbox.com:3000/my_objects
```

and I want it to be

```
http://mydomein.devbox.com:3000/my_objects/index
```

How can I force the URL to be “/index” instead of what its appearing as now?

**Edit:** Here are the logs when visiting /my_objects/index:

```
Started GET "/my_objects/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-12 12:17:25 -0500
Processing by MyObjectsController#index as HTML
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a nested array to Active Record finder methods is deprecated and will be removed. Flatten your array before using it for 'IN' conditions. (called  from country_code_select at /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/runtrax/app/helpers/user_form_helper.rb:83)
  Rendered my_objects/_add.html.erb (31.0ms)
  Rendered my_objects/index.html.erb within layouts/race (46.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered my_objects/_tabs.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 308ms (Views: 301.9ms | ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
```

**Edit:** Here is the relevant portion from the config/routes.rb file …

```
  get 'my_objects/index'
  get 'my_objects/create'
  resources :my_objects do
    collection do
      post 'create'
      get 'import'
      get 'index' => 'my_objects/index'
      get 'search'
      get 'stats'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirected URL by rails convention is redirecting to the index action. Check your logs to see what happening.  If you do /my_objects/index, you're telling rails you want the my_object with ID = index.

Comment: I don't believe what you're saying is accurate, because I can type "/my_objects/index" into a web browser and the page I want to see if rendered properly . Per your request, I have included the logs when typing such a URL.  When I redirect in my controller, I want the result to be the same as typing in "/my_objects/index."  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your routes.rb because there you can specify how you get a route like this:

> > get 'my_objects/index' => 'my_objects#index'

and then in the controller you just do a

> > redirect_to my_objects

Comment: I added teh config/routes.rb file, whcih includes yoru suggestion and changed my controller redirect to be "format.html { redirect_to controller: "my_objects", notice: 'Saved successfully.' }" but I'm still redirected to "/my_objects" instead of "/my_objects/index".

Comment: then do it as a redirect  get  '/my_objects', to: redirect('/my_objects/index'). let me know but yes it's weird that you could force /index in the url and it worked because index in that case would be the id. why do you want to show /index? Rails' framework is based on convention over configuration principle and so the convention is for the collection of all objects from the model MyObjects that you have to have restful routes, and so my_objects_path would show that collection @ .../my_objects through the controller's index  action. read more here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: When you say, "then do it as a redirect get '/my_objects', to: redirect('/my_objects/index')", what do you mean exactly?  Do what?

Comment: i mean put this:       get '/my_objects', to: redirect('/my_objects/index')         in your routes.rb and in your controller just do redirect_to my_objects

Comment: That didn't work either (still get redirected to /my_objects instead of /my_objects/index).  I edietd my question to include the fact that I have "get 'my_objects/index'" in my config/routes.rb file, a fact, maybe meaningless, that I forgot to include when you originally asked for the config/routes.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

In the routes change this line

```
get "index" => "my_object#index"
```

To

```
get "index" => "my_object#index", as: :my_object_index
```

Then redirect to that path

```
redirect_to my_object_index_path, notice: "saved successfully"
```

Comment: It's happening because rails defaults to omitting index from the URL. You need to explicitly name the route as my_objects_path is still using the default route created when you call resources :my_objects

Comment: Also your syntax is wrong when you are calling redirect_to. Don't add controller: "my_objects". Just use the path. Exactly how I've done it here

Comment: No dice.  I changed my config/routes.rb file to what you suggested but this line that you gave, "format.html { redirecct_to my_object_index_path, notice: 'Saved successfully.' }" redirects to /my_objects and not /my_objects/index .